# Здравствуйте, я только начинаю программировать, прохожу ветвления. Вот столкнулся с проблемой

Tags: java

[image]

полазал по форумам, ничего полезного не нашел при вводе числа которое должно быть нечетным , при написани num2%2!=0(выделяет оранжевым) при этом написании, которое я как почитал правильно выделяет красным. Что вообще значит выделение оранжевым? Вот тоже такой вопрос потому что на 16 строчке кода else if выделяет оранжевым. Зарнее спасибо

Comment: Можно мышкой навестись на это место и увидеть конкретный текст о том, что это значит

Comment: А если играть в угадайку, то, скорее всего, пишет (предупреждает), что тело условия пустое....

Comment: ну при написании num2%2!=0 пишет что это условие будет выполняться всегда, дописал программу вроде работает, но странно что выделяет оранжевым

Comment: Ну наведи на оранжевое-то

Comment: С красным правильно пишет.....потому что первое условие было на ==  ..... если оно не выполнилось значит всегда !==

Comment: if (num1%2==0 && num2%2==0){
            num1 = num1 /2;
            num2 = num2 /2;
            num3 = num1+num2;
            System.out.println(num3);

        }else if(num1%2==0){
            num1 = num1 /2;
            num3 = num1+num2;
            System.out.println(num3);


        }else if(num2%2==0){
            num2=num2/2;
            num3 = num2+num1;
            System.out.println(num3);
        }else{
            System.out.println(num1+num2);
        }
    } 
так? я правильно понял вашу мысль?

Comment: Вроде как именно это в точности и написано в тексте задачи   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Volk [tag:обучение] вообще удалить надо: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5800/532877

Answer (score 2):

!== Не существует в джаве, думаю скобки лишнии во втором условии. можно отключить предупреждения visual studo. оранжевым потому что это и за тела пустого либо некретичное предупреждение другой причины

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer num1 = new Random().nextInt();
    Integer num2 = new Random().nextInt();
    if (((num1%2) == 0)&&((num2%2) == 0)) {
        System.out.println(num1/2+"\n"+num2/2);
    } else if (((num1%2) == 0)) {
        System.out.println(num1/2);
    } else if (((num2%2) == 0)) {
        System.out.println(num2/2);
    } else if (((num1%2) == 0)) {
        System.out.println(num1+num2);
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]